# playwright drag and drop

Tags: node.js, drag-and-drop, playwright

Trying to test some drag and drop functionality, looks like playwright doesn't have drag and drop functionality so I'm using `mouse.move()`, `mouse.down()` & `mouse.up()`.

However my attempts seem to be failing, the target is not being moved. Code below:

```js
test("drag and drop test", async () => {
  await page.goto("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp");
  await page.waitForSelector("#accept-choices");
  await page.click("#accept-choices");
  await page.waitForSelector("#div1");
  let xStart, yStart, xFinish, yFinish, elementHandle, rect;
  elementHandle = await page.$("#div1");
  rect = await elementHandle.boundingBox();
  xStart = rect.x + rect.width / 2;
  yStart = rect.y + rect.height / 2;
  elementHandle = await page.$("#div2");
  rect = await elementHandle.boundingBox();
  xFinish = rect.x + rect.width / 2;
  yFinish = rect.y + rect.height / 2;
  console.log(`move from (${xStart}, ${yStart}) to (${xFinish},${yFinish})`);
  await page.screenshot({ path: "before drag.png" });
  await page.mouse.move(xStart, yStart);
  await page.mouse.down();
  await page.mouse.move(xFinish, yFinish);
  await page.mouse.up();
  await page.screenshot({ path: "after drag.png" });
});
```

Comment: You can vote for drag and drop support here https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/1094

Comment: Dropped my vote thanks, any thoughts on if the above code should work?

Comment: The only working test is using the dispatchEvent function https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/0ee9050f1bb9406775438cc52e4c8599a5f266d4/test/dispatchevent.spec.ts#L129 but it could be quite tricky to find what's the dataTransfer object you'd need to pass.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Version 1.13.0 added API methods for that. Check out the [documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-drag-and-drop).
Copied from the docs:

> `page.dragAndDrop(source, target[, options])`
>
> - source: `string`
> - target: `string`
> - options: `Object`
>
>   - force `boolean` Whether to bypass the actionability checks. Defaults to false.
>   - noWaitAfter `boolean` Actions that initiate navigations are waiting for these navigations to happen and for pages to start
>     loading. You can opt out of waiting via setting this flag. You would
>     only need this option in the exceptional cases such as navigating to
>     inaccessible pages. Defaults to false.
>   - timeout `number` Maximum time in milliseconds, defaults to 30 seconds, pass 0 to disable timeout. The default value can be changed
>     by using the `browserContext.setDefaultTimeout(timeout)` or
>     `page.setDefaultTimeout(timeout)` methods.
>   - trial: `boolean` When set, this method only performs the actionability checks and skips the action. Defaults to false. Useful
>     to wait until the element is ready for the action without performing
>     it.
> - returns: `Promise<void>`

Answer (score 11):

I've also struggled with how to make `drag and drop` possible with playwright.

I needed to move vertically, for example,

**before reorder**
1
2
3

**after reorder applied**
2
1
3

```
    const exampleOneDrag = await page.$(
      `[data-testid="${exampleOne}-drag-icon-button"]`
    )
    const exampleTwoDrag = await page.$(
      `[data-testid="${exampleTwo}-drag-icon-button"]`
    )
    const oneBoundingBox = await exampleOneDrag?.boundingBox()
    const twoBoundingBox = await exampleTwoDrag?.boundingBox()

    if (oneBoundingBox && twoBoundingBox) {
      await page.mouse.move(
        oneBoundingBox.x + oneBoundingBox.width / 2,
        oneBoundingBox.y + oneBoundingBox.height / 2,
        { steps: 5 }
      )
      await page.mouse.down()
      await page.mouse.move(
        twoBoundingBox.x + twoBoundingBox.width / 2,
        twoBoundingBox.y + twoBoundingBox.height / 2,
        { steps: 5 }
      )
      await page.mouse.up()
    }
```

The keypoint to be able to work this was `steps:5` options. I am not entirely sure what it does, but I've found from here : https://github.com/codeceptjs/CodeceptJS/blob/e815d82af028e904051b5b6c70873164e1df1bfd/lib/helper/Playwright.js#L2289-L2307e

hope this works for you. I think your case, you should change like this

```
  await page.mouse.move(xStart, xFinish);
  await page.mouse.down();
  await page.mouse.move(yStart, yFinish);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, even with `step` option defined, I am unable to get my example working, have you got a working example to share? Were you able to get drag and drop working in your code to move vertically?

Comment: @user3770935 Sure, I've figured out that `step` breaks the path from start to endpoint into steps and do that many smaller moves. First, I would suggest increasing step (we did from 5 to 15). If you can see it is reordering but not applying, maybe it's too quick to finish their task, so I've added  ```await page.waitForTimeout(4000)```  after ```await page.mouse.up()```. Hope it helps your situation.

Comment: looks like its a well known issue, HTML5 drag events not triggered by mouse movement. See this thread: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1376
As @hardkoded commented, and seen here https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1366#issuecomment-589828387 seems we need to `dispatchEvent`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me in my own drag and drop library for vue [vue-fluid-dnd](https://github.com/carlosjorger/vue-fluid-dnd):

```js
async function dragDrop(
  page: Page,
  originSelector: string,
  destinationSelector: string
) {
  const originElement = await page.waitForSelector(originSelector);
  const destinationElement = await page.waitForSelector(destinationSelector);

  const originElementBox = await originElement.boundingBox();
  const destinationElementBox = await destinationElement.boundingBox();
  if (!originElementBox || !destinationElementBox) {
    return;
  }
  await page.mouse.move(
    originElementBox.x + originElementBox.width / 2,
    originElementBox.y + originElementBox.height / 2
  );
  await page.mouse.down();
  // I added more steps to see a smoother animation.
  await page.mouse.move(
    destinationElementBox.x + destinationElementBox.width / 2,
    destinationElementBox.y + destinationElementBox.height / 2,
    { steps: 20 }
  );
  await page.mouse.up();
}
```