# Playwright - drag and drop files

Tags: javascript, file-upload, drag-and-drop, playwright

I'm looking at automating a drag and drop scenario using Playwright.  I found this code which is meant to do just this:

```js
// Read your file into a buffer.
const buffer = readFileSync('./runtime_config/common/file.pdf');

// Create the DataTransfer and File
const dataTransfer = await scope.page.evaluateHandle((data) => {
    const dt = new DataTransfer();
    // Convert the buffer to a hex array
    const file = new File([data.toString('hex')], 'file.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf' });
    dt.items.add(file);
    return dt;
}, buffer);

// Now dispatch
await page.dispatchEvent('YOUR_TARGET_SELECTOR', 'drop', { dataTransfer });
```

This code was found on this github post https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/10667
When I try to use this code, I get an error that '**scope is not defined**'

I can't see how this would work, nor does the post have any info.  I've reached out to the poster but no reply yet, so thought I'd try here.  Anyone know how this would work?

(I tried modify the line to be `this.page.evaluateHandle((data)` which doesn't error at runtime, but all I am getting is a 15B file called 'file.pdf' in the UI.  I have console.log the buffer and it does appear to be valid.)

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718915/playwright-drag-and-drop) help you ?

Comment: Fraid not - that looks like it only handles things on screen, when the original code would drop a file onto an area.